# Fortran 77 complains about common blocks

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, fortran-common-block

I'm using with gfortran 4.8.2 on FreeBSD 9.2 to create some executable files. There are three files, one C file and two Fortran 77 files where I'm using two routines with one common block.

The problem is that I receive an error of multiple definitions from gfortran compiler.

**requests which I had sent to server:**

```
autoreconf
./configure
make
```

**di8810.c**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(argc,argv)

int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  if (argc != 4)
    {
          exit(99);
    }
         gds100(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3]);
}
```

**gds100.f**

```
SUBROUTINE GDS100(AUSGABE,FORMAT,FILENAME)
CHARACTER*4097 EBUF   
CHARACTER*264 BUFFER      
CHARACTER*1 CBUFFER(264)      
CHARACTER*1 CEBUF(4097)      
CHARACTER*1 FORMAT


INTEGER*2 INULL      
CHARACTER*1 LTEXT(112)      
COMMON /GDSCB2/ EBUF      
EQUIVALENCE (EBUF,CEBUF(1))      
EQUIVALENCE (CEBUF(4097),INULL)     
DATA INULL /0/     
...
END
```

**gds102.f**

```
SUBROUTINE GDS102

CHARACTER*264 BUFFER      
CHARACTER*1 CBUFFER(264)     
CHARACTER*4097 EBUF      
CHARACTER*1 CEBUF(4097)      
INTEGER*2 INULL      
INTEGER POIADR    
COMMON /GDSCB2/ EBUF     
EQUIVALENCE (BUFFER,CBUFFER(1))      
EQUIVALENCE (EBUF,CEBUF(1))      
EQUIVALENCE (CEBUF(4097),INULL)      
DATA IWOGRZ /4096/      
DATA INULL /0/      
ENTRY GDSUMS(N)
...
END
```

**The error is:**

```
make  all-am
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -DDI88xx -g -O2 -MT src/di8810-di8810.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/di8810-di8810.Tpo -c -o src/di8810-di8810.o `test -f 'src/di8810.c' || echo './'`src/di8810.c
mv -f src/.deps/di8810-di8810.Tpo src/.deps/di8810-di8810.Po
gfortran -cpp  -fcheck=all -fno-underscoring  -DDI88xx -g -O2 -c -o src/di8810-gds100.o `test -f 'src/gds100.f' || echo './'`src/gds100.f
gfortran -cpp  -fcheck=all -fno-underscoring  -DDI88xx -g -O2 -c -o src/di8810-gds102.o `test -f 'src/gds102.f' || echo './'`src/gds102.f
gfortran -cpp  -fcheck=all -fno-underscoring  -DDI88xx -g -O2    -o di8810 src/di8810-di8810.o  src/di8810-gds100.o src/di8810-gds102.o
src/di8810-gds102.o: In function `gds102':
/.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t/src/gds102.f:2: multiple definition of `gdscb2'
src/di8810-gds100.o:/.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t/src/gds100.f:1: first defined here
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
*** [di8810] Error code 1

Stop in /.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t.
*** [all] Error code 1

Stop in /.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t.

Stop in /.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t.
*** [all] Error code 1

Stop in /.amd_mnt/blnn728x/home/sayik_bo/di8810_t.
```

It's driving me nuts. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also have a function called gdscb2?

Comment: No, only the name in the common block.

Comment: can you  trim it down to minimal code to reproduce the problem.  Equivalence-ing a 2-byte integer to the last position in a char array seems odd. Then you initialize that same location separately in each routine, also odd.

Comment: @george, I will try this on monday and will report. The code actually works on HP-UX and the HP Fortran compiler but we are trying to move to a standard platform (FreeBSD, Linux) mid-term.

Comment: @george, please rephrase as an answer regarding "Then you initialize that same location separately in each routine, also odd.". I removed `DATA INULL /0/` in `gds102.f` and was able to compile and link. Though, I have another problem with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elaborating on my comment

the common statement causes the compiler to allocate  global  storage for `GDSCB2`.

The symbols `CEBUF,INULL` are by `Equivalence` essentially pointers to the global storage.

Now the two `data inull/0/` statements are redundantly initializing the same 
location in global memory.  I don't know if that a problem or not..just something to look at.

The other thing i see there is inull is 2 bytes (probably..or maybe more but certainly not 1)
yet it is equivalenced to the very last byte of the global character array.  ie the initilization writes to data beyond the allocated space.

If at all feasible i would get rid of the common all together. Allocate the storage in the calling program and pass it as an argument to the subroutines.

in any case just do `CEBUF(4097)=char(0)` instead of using inull like that.